# vb.net - Creating a dynamic connecting line between two draggable controls at runtime

Tags: vb.net, runtime, line, drawing

In my winforms app, there is like a 'flow design' view where controls can be added to the designer from a toolbox at runtime. The user can drag these around and position them wherever they like and set each controls associated properties etc.

As this is representative of a flow, I'd like to have connecting lines drawn between the controls in the appropriate order, but i'm not sure how best to approach it. Some of my controls may need to be able to have multiple connecting lines feeding into them to cater for different logic outcomes too.

I tried a quick implementation using graphics.drawline and calculating the centre of each control and that works for the initial drawing, however I have no control over the line once its drawn and if the control on either side is moved, then line doesnt stay 'connected' to it, but instead is static. It also strangely 'rubs out' if a control is dragged over it, so I've pretty much ruled that out as an option.

Has anyone done something like this before? How did you tackle it and what were the challenges you faced etc?

Comment: "It also strangely 'rubs out' if a control is dragged over it, so I've pretty much ruled that out as an option."  Sounds like you've incorrectly used `CreateGrahics()` instead of `e.Graphics` from the Paint() event of the container form/control.

Comment: "however I have no control over the line once its drawn and if the control on either side is moved, then line doesnt stay 'connected' to it, but instead is static." You'd create a `List(Of something)` to hold the information about connecting lines and iterate over that in the Paint() event of your container, drawing all the lines in turn.  When something moves, you'd raise a custom event notifying the parent container that it needs to draw its lines in new positions.

Comment: You have to make a major design decision here, (1) Draw the lines on the container that holds the other things `(lightweight lines)`, or (2) Create a non-rectangular UserControl to represent the connecting lines by modifying the region property of the usercontrol `(heavy lines)`.

Comment: This all assumes you're working in WinForms?...as this wouldn't really be an issue if you were working in WPF.

Comment: Your question is formulated in a way that it's difficult to answer, because it seems like you're looking for a ground-up solution, while you actually do have some existing code upon which you want to build, so you should post a minimal version of your code that someone can modify to make work.

Comment: So a few answers.... yes, definately winforms, not WPF. 
Perhaps i did incorrectly user CreateGraphics()... I'll check that out.  

I'm not looking for a ground up solution, but rather opinion or a nudge in a certain direction so that i might do my own research and find the path on my own thereafter, although that might not be necessary if my previous assumptions were wrong and the issues I faced were of my own making.